# Widget с определенными TextView

Tags: java, android, android-widgets

Как показывать только те `TextView`, которые нужно?

```
public class NewAppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId) {
        CharSequence widgetAdr = NewAppWidgetConfigureActivity.loadAdrPref(context, appWidgetId);
        CharSequence widgetTime = NewAppWidgetConfigureActivity.loadTimePref(context, appWidgetId);
        CharSequence widgetDesc = NewAppWidgetConfigureActivity.loadDescPref(context, appWidgetId);
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);
        if (PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getBoolean("chkadr", true)) views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_adress, widgetAdr);
        else if (PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getBoolean("chktime", true)) views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_time, widgetTime);
        else if (PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getBoolean("chkdesc", true)) views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_desc, widgetDesc);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            NewAppWidgetConfigureActivity.deleteAdrPref(context, appWidgetId);
            NewAppWidgetConfigureActivity.deleteTimePref(context, appWidgetId);
            NewAppWidgetConfigureActivity.deleteDescPref(context, appWidgetId);
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
public class NewAppWidgetConfigureActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String PREFS_NAME = ".NewAppWidget";
    private static final String PREF_PREFIX_KEY = "appwidget_";
    int mAppWidgetId = AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID;
    CheckBox chkAdr, chkTime, chkDesc;

    public NewAppWidgetConfigureActivity() {
        super();
    }

    static void saveAdrPref(Context context, int appWidgetId, String text) {
        context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0).edit().putString(PREF_PREFIX_KEY + appWidgetId, text).apply();
    }

    static String loadAdrPref(Context context, int appWidgetId) {
        SharedPreferences adr = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        String titleValue = adr.getString(PREF_PREFIX_KEY + appWidgetId, null);
        if (titleValue != null) return titleValue;
        else return context.getString(R.string.appwidget_adress);
    }

    static void deleteAdrPref(Context context, int appWidgetId) {
        context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0).edit().remove(PREF_PREFIX_KEY + appWidgetId).apply();
    }

    static void saveTimePref(Context context, int appWidgetId, String text) {
        context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0).edit().putString(PREF_PREFIX_KEY + appWidgetId, text).apply();
    }

    static String loadTimePref(Context context, int appWidgetId) {
        SharedPreferences time = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        String titleValue = time.getString(PREF_PREFIX_KEY + appWidgetId, null);
        if (titleValue != null) return titleValue;
        else return context.getString(R.string.appwidget_time);
    }

    static void deleteTimePref(Context context, int appWidgetId) {
        context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0).edit().remove(PREF_PREFIX_KEY + appWidgetId).apply();
    }

    static void saveDescPref(Context context, int appWidgetId, String text) {
        context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0).edit().putString(PREF_PREFIX_KEY + appWidgetId, text).apply();
    }

    static String loadDescPref(Context context, int appWidgetId) {
        SharedPreferences desc = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        String titleValue = desc.getString(PREF_PREFIX_KEY + appWidgetId, null);
        if (titleValue != null) return titleValue;
        else return context.getString(R.string.appwidget_desc);
    }

    static void deleteDescPref(Context context, int appWidgetId) {
        context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0).edit().remove(PREF_PREFIX_KEY + appWidgetId).apply();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_app_widget_configure);
        chkAdr = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxAdr);
        chkAdr.setChecked(false);
        chkTime = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxTime);
        chkTime.setChecked(false);
        chkDesc = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxDesc);
        chkDesc.setChecked(false);
        findViewById(R.id.add_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Context context = NewAppWidgetConfigureActivity.this;
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.checkBoxAdr:
                        if (chkAdr.isChecked()) {
                            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(NewAppWidgetConfigureActivity.this).edit().clear().apply();
                            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(NewAppWidgetConfigureActivity.this).edit().putBoolean("chkadr", true).apply();
                            saveAdrPref(context, mAppWidgetId, getString(R.string.appwidget_adress));
                        }
                        break;
                    case R.id.checkBoxTime:
                        if (chkTime.isChecked()) {
                            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(NewAppWidgetConfigureActivity.this).edit().clear().apply();
                            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(NewAppWidgetConfigureActivity.this).edit().putBoolean("chktime", true).apply();
                            saveTimePref(context, mAppWidgetId, getString(R.string.appwidget_time));
                        }
                        break;
                    case R.id.checkBoxDesc:
                        if (chkDesc.isChecked()) {
                            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(NewAppWidgetConfigureActivity.this).edit().clear().apply();
                            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(NewAppWidgetConfigureActivity.this).edit().putBoolean("chkdesc", true).apply();
                            saveDescPref(context, mAppWidgetId, getString(R.string.appwidget_desc));
                        }
                        break;
                }
                NewAppWidget.updateAppWidget(context, AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context), mAppWidgetId);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, new Intent().putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mAppWidgetId));
                finish();
            }
        });
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) mAppWidgetId = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        if (mAppWidgetId == AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) finish();
    }

}
```

P.S. Вроде бы все в жизни попробовал, но Widget для меня стал просто новым космосом.

В связи с этим - Я вообще правильно делаю? или такое нельзя сделать?

Comment: Коллега, вопрос пока даже не про виджеты, а про использование shared preferences. Мне кажется, или saveAdrPref, saveTimePref и saveDescPref формируют ключ из одного и того же префикса, что значит, что затирают данные друг другу?       context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0).edit().putString(PREF_PREFIX_KEY + appWidgetId, text).apply();

Comment: Второе. На примере saveAdrPref(). В зависимости от чекбокса туда или будет записана строчка R.string.appwidget_adress, или не будет. loadAdrPref() этот параметр прочитает. если туда ничего не записано, то вернет строчку R.string.appwidget_adress. Что значит, что R.string.appwidget_adress вернется всегда. Похоже, здесь закралась ошибка.

Comment: Третье. Работа с defaultSharedPreferences еще более загадочна. При обработке каждого чекбокса, эти преференсы будут очищены полностью. То есть одновременно там может выжить только одно булевское значение.

Comment: Там, где формируется удаленная вьюха, флаги проверяются if-else-else. То есть может присутствовать только одно значение одновременно. Тогда два вопроса: почему в активити используется три чекбокса, а не группа из трех радиобаттонов? И зачем в лэйауте удаленной вьюхи три поля? Если значение может быть только одно, то и поле должно быть только одно, оно будет заполняться в зависимости от флагов нужной строкой.

Comment: Дальше. Заметьте, что при хранении строк учитывается id виджета, а при хранении флагов - нет. Это значит, что настройка второго и последующих экземпляров виджета изменит поведение первого (и всех существующих). Я не уверен, что так и надо.

Comment: В общем, куча вопросов, и ни один из них не является специфичным для виджета. Код непосредственно виджета выглядит технически корректным. Я про виджеты сейчас немного расскажу, но сначала нужно определиться, что же именно хочется, и реализовать это в коде более однозначно.

Comment: Та просто идея одна затаилась у меня:) "И зачем в лэйауте удаленной вьюхи три поля? Если значение может быть только одно, то и поле должно быть только одно, оно будет заполняться в зависимости от флагов нужной строкой." - Глаза открыли, просто, спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Про виджеты нужно понимать, что это многокомпонентная система. Состоит она из следующих частей:

1. Приложение, которое формирует виджет.
2. Приложение, которое показывает виджет. Как правило, это ланчер, хотя технически возможно в любое приложение вставить механизм показа виджетов.
3. Операционная система, которая связывает эти два приложения.

Обратите внимание, что формируют и показывают данные два разных приложения. Это значит, что у виджета не может быть интерфейса в привычном нам понимании: между приложениями могут быть переданы только статические сериализованные данные.

Поэтому по сути RemoteViews - это слегка преобразованный layout. Inflater будет запущен сильно позже, тем приложением, которое виджет будет показывать. Inflater для RemoteViews сначала создает объекты в памяти, затем заменяет им данные для отображения. Данные эти помещаются в RemoteViews с помощью команд вроде [setTextViewText()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setTextViewText(int,%20java.lang.CharSequence)). Этих команд ограниченное количество, все они находятся в классе [RemoteViews](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html), ничего друго передать в виджет нельзя. Если нужны красоты - формируйте и передавайте битмап.

Никакого собственного поведения в виджета нет, также как нет возможности что-то изменить с помощью setVisibility() или setText(). Если приложение хочет изменить что-то - оно формирует новый RemoteViews и передает его AppWidgetManager'у.

Взаимодействие с пользователем осуществляется с помощью PendingIntent. Это точно такой же PendingIntent, что используется в AlarmManager'е и нотификациях. Хотите сделать в виджете пульт управления плеером - сформируйте по PendingIntent на каждую кнопку. PendingIntent может быт любой, хоть броткаст, хоть запуск Activity.

На этом все интересное заканчивается. Дальше начинается механика приложения, формирующего эту удаленную вьюху. Состоит этот механизм из трех частей:

1. BroadcastReceiver, с помощью которого приложение получает извещения о том, что создан или удален экземпляр виджета, или что нужно обновить виджет. [AppWidgetProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html), от которого мы должны унаследовать наш класс виджета, содержит код разбора приходящих в onReceive() параметров, и ничего больше. Исключительно для нашего удобства.
2. Механизм по формированию и отправки RemoveViews. Этот механизм никак не связан с AppWidgetProvider! То есть приложение может само принять решение изменить внешний вид виджета, сформировать новый и отдать в операционку через специальный сервис. Более того, поскольку операционка запрашивает обновление виджета не чаще, чем раз в 15 минут, при создании, например, виджета-часов, приложение должно будет само формировать RemoteViewы раз в минуту или даже раз в секунду.

   Этот механизм может быть реализован где угодно, хоть в Service. Единственное различие - AppWidgetProvider предоставит нужные константы и классы, а в своем Service их придется получать самим.
3. Activity, с помощью которой виджет настраивается. Обычная Activity, функционирующая по обычным законам. Одним из параметров получает Id экземпляра виджета, который настраивается в данный момент. Потом данные, сформированные в работе этой Activity, можно будет использовать при формировании RemoteViews. Если какая-либо настройка виджета или настройка отдельных экземпляров не нужна, то этой Activity может и не быть.

Все остальное - бойлерплейт и рутина, описанные [в документации](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html). Их придется терпеливо, шаг за шагом реализовать.