# Отображение текста в RemoteView при создании Widget Android

Tags: java, android, android-widgets

Не отображается текст, который хардкорю в `RemoteView` в `Widget`.
Текст в `xml` отображается без проблем. Ниже листинг.

1. Манифест:

   ```
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.alex.dzlesson06">
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

       <application
           android:allowBackup="true"
           android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
           android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:supportsRtl="true"
           android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

           <receiver
               android:name=".MyWidget">
               <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
               </intent-filter>
               <meta-data
                   android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                   android:resource="@xml/widget_metadata"/>
           </receiver>
       </application>
   </manifest>
   ```
2. Layout виджета:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/widget_latitude"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="TEST"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:textSize="18sp"/>

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/widget_longitude"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:textSize="18sp"/>

   </LinearLayout>
   ```
3. Мета-данные:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <appwidget-provider
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:initialLayout="@layout/widget"
       android:minHeight="40dp"
       android:minWidth="110dp"
       android:updatePeriodMillis="0">
   </appwidget-provider>
   ```
4. Код виджета:

   ```
   public class MyWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

   @Override
   public void onEnabled(Context context) {
       super.onEnabled(context);
   }

   @Override
   public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
       super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

       for (int id : appWidgetIds){
           RemoteViews remoteViews = new  RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
           remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_latitude, "MY WIDGET");
           appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);

       }
   }
   ```

И ещё вопрос вдогонку. Т.к. этот `Widget` без приложения. Как его можно дебажить?

Answer (score 0):

Дебажить втрадиционном смысле никак нельзя, потому что RemoteViews не имеют поведения, это статические данные для отображения, я об этом недавно писал: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/611785/193715

Во-вторых, в коде есть странность. Обратите внимание, что updateAppWidget() есть в двух вариантах: первым параметром id определенной view, и первым параметром список id. Если вы используете вариант со списком, то зачем вам внешний `for`?

В-третьих, код у вас выглядит нормально. Единственная гипотеза, что после переустановки приложения, создающего виджет, он (виджет) не апдейтится. Попробуйте создать новый экземпляр виджета, вероятно, с ним будет уже все хорошо.