# Можно ли создавать виджеты (на рабочий стол телефона) в fmx rad c++builder?

Tags: android, виджет, radstudio, android-widgets, firemonkey

Можно ли создавать виджеты (на рабочий стол телефона) в `fmx rad c++builder`?
Не могу найти в интернете информации вообще. Подскажите или ссылку какую киньте.

Comment: Боюсь, что создатели виджетов на C++ здесь встречаются крайне редко. :)

Answer (score 0):

Я какое-то время назад пытался рассказать о том, как на самом деле устроены виджеты рабочего стола. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/611785/193715

Виджет - это `BroadcastReceiver` и генератор `RemoteViews`. Соответственно, если вы с помощью вашего инструмента сможете описать `BroadcastReceiver`, создать объект `RemoteViews` и передать его в `AppWidgetManager`, то ответ "да, возможно".